# IOS Swift - deletedObjects NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to delete all the rows in a table of core data (DatiGame), consists of 4 fields.
foto_bottone0
foto_bottone1
foto_master
vinto
and the table has no other relationships.

but the operation DeletedObjects returns the following error:

'(NSManagedObject) -> $ T4' is not identical to 'NSSet'

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CoreData

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    // 1
    var appDell:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
    var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDell.managedObjectContext!
    // 2
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "DatiGame")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    println("pre fetch ")
    // 3

    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    if (results?.count > 0) {

        for result: AnyObject in results! {

  --> ERROR deleteObjects <--     
               context.deletedObjects(result as NSManagedObject)       // ERROR 
                                   '(NSManagedObject) -> $ T4' is not identical to 'NSSet'" 

             context.save(nil)
        }
    }
 }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }

}
```

Please, can someone help me?
other question:
you can delete all the rows in a table without looping? thanks thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the wrong function. Deleting a managed object is done with
`context.deleteObject(anObject)`.

`deletedObjects` is a property that (roughly speaking) *returns* all objects
that have been marked for deletion.

Additional remarks:

- For better performance,save the context *after* all objects have been deleted.
- *Use* the `error` parameter for diagnostics instead of passing `nil`.
- Better use optional binding to check for the success of `executeFetchRequest()` 
  instead of testing `results?.count`.

Example:

```
var error: NSError?
let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
if let objects = results  {
    for object in objects as [NSManagedObject] {
        context.deleteObject(object)
    }
    if !context.save(&error) {
        println("save failed: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    }
} else {
    println("fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
}
```